# Disable scrolling a ScrollView by gesture

Tags: android, view, scroll

how can I disable the scrolling of a Scrollview, by the user? I want to scroll it by code

Comment: Have you [done any research](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+disable+scrollview+scrolling)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question:

I've done some research, and the following works the best:

```
scroll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{ 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        return true; 
    }
});
```

As parsed from my working code.